# Scanner not finding file

Tags: java

I have researched how to use the scanner method (as I am new to it) and my code looks the exact same as others but still it doesn't find the file. My .txt file is located in the src folder.

It throws the following error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: StationInfo.txt (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:611)
    at traingui.code.TrainGui$1.run(TrainGui.java:37)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Here is my code which implements the Scanner:

```
package gui.code;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Gui {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()   {

            //running the gui
            public void run() {
                makeAndShowGUI();



                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    }



            }

        });

}
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't run from the `src` folder; use the full path, load it from your home folder, or figure out where you are actually running your code.

Comment: If your file is in the src folder you can load it as a resource. Conventionally you would put it somewhere in src/main/resources and it will end up on the classpath. You can then use getResourceAsStream()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try with an absolute path (e.g: C:\StationInfo.txt)
2. Or try put that file in the same folder of your *.java file or when you run application, try put that file in same folder of your *.class file

Comment: Thats the thing though, it's in my folder with all the .java files!

Comment: When you run, where is your *.class file?

Answer (score 0):

When creating an instance of a Scanner from a file (using `new File("StationInfo.txt")`), the default file location is within the folder that you're calling the command from. Try moving the `txt` file to the location where you run the code, or provide a full path to the file (ex. `new File("C:\Users\...\...\StationInfo.txt")`).

Answer (score 0):

Although there are many ways to find, fetch and load resources in application but simply if you wish to fetch the file kept in src folder then you can try below code.

```
File f = new File("src/StationInfo.txt");
```